# Bad substitution in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I'm trying to get a script working to add swap space to a VPS, as a workaround a la [this method.](http://linux-problem-solver.blogspot.com/2013/08/create-fake-swap-in-openvz-vps-if-you-get-swapon-failed-operation-not-permitted-error.html)  I thought I had it working but now, each time I get the error: `fakeswap.sh: 5: Bad substitution` whenever I try to execute it thusly: `sudo sh fakeswap.sh`.

Below is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

SWAP="${1:-512}"

NEW="$[SWAP*1024]"; TEMP="${NEW//?/ }"; OLD="${TEMP:1}0"

umount /proc/meminfo 2> /dev/null
sed "/^Swap\(Total\|Free\):/s,$OLD,$NEW," /proc/meminfo > /etc/fake_meminfo
mount --bind /etc/fake_meminfo /proc/meminfo

free -m
```

Clearly the substitution that seems to be failing is on the line: `NEW="$[SWAP*1024]"; TEMP="${NEW//?/ }"; OLD="${TEMP:1}0"`

I'm somewhat ashamed to say that I don't REALLY understand what's supposed to happen on that line (apart from the fact that we seem to be declaring variables that are all derivatives of SWAP in one way or another).  I gather that the lines below substitute new constants into a dummy configuration file (for lack of a better term) but I don't get how the variables `TEMP` and `OLD` are being defined.

Anyway, I was wondering if anyone might be able to see why this substitution isn't working...and maybe even help me understand what might be be happening when `TEMP` and `OLD` are defined?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You might look closely at what that script does. Hint: It **doesn't** actually change the amount of swap you have available.

Comment: @neanderslob OT: I cannot mount the resultant file:
mount: /etc/fake_meminfo is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: cannot mount /etc/fake_meminfo read-only  
... did you ever see this

Comment: I wonder how you go about restoring your proc/meminfo after no longer needing the faking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sh` is not `bash`. The `sh` shell doesn't recognize some valid `bash` substitutions.

The intention of that script is that it be executable. You would do that by

```
chmod a+x fakeswap.sh
```

after which you can run it simply by typing

```
./fakeswap.sh
```

(assuming it is in the current working directory; if not, use the full path.)

By the way, `TEMP` is a number of spaces equal to the length of `NEW` and `OLD` is the result of changing the last space in `TEMP` to `0`. So `OLD` and `NEW` have the same length, meaning that the `sed` substitution won't change the size of the file.

Comment: Wow, major pitfall on my part; thanks for setting me straight!  (Works fine now)  I suppose I should have deduced this from bash's acronym.  The blog I got this hack off of claimed to use sh to execute the script.  Weird... Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: On some OSes, /bin/sh is actually a copy/link of /bin/bash, and as a result you can get away with using `sh` on a bash script; on other OSes (like yours -- Ubuntu, by any chance?), this won't work.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Why yes it is Ubuntu! Thanks for the explanation; that seems like a good thing to know.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Note that invoking `bash` as `sh` causes it to implicitly `set -o posix` so its behaviour is still different in a few details. In general, it's unwise (on any OS) to assume that `sh` has any extensions to what Posix requires.

Comment: I got `./fakeswap.sh: line 3: /proc/meminfo: Permission denied`

Comment: @salem: you need root privileges to do that stuff

Comment: I'm root , but I think the host provider disable it from OpenVZ setting

Comment: @salem: could be. Anyway it has little to do with the substance of this question.